# Logitech gamepad F710 and ubuntu and as an input to a python program

Tags: ubuntu, python, game-controller, logitech-gamepad

I would like to use the Logitech F710 gamepad as an input device to a python program. I am using Ubuntu. I do not really know where to start, so here are a few questions:

1. How does Ubuntu detect the gamepad?
2. If the gamepad is recognized within Ubuntu, how would I interact with this device via a python script?
3. If this is not easy to do in Ubuntu, how would I interact with the gamepad via a python script in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As a USB HID device.
2. Via the [event subsystem](https://github.com/gvalkov/python-evdev).
3. Uh...

Comment: Thank you. With regards to recognizing a USB HID device, do I need to install drivers for the gamepad?

Comment: No. All modern Linuxes have the USB HID driver already available, either built-in or as a module.

Answer (score 1):

Input devices register as `/dev/input/eventX` in Linux, to interact with them you have to open that pseudo file and read from it.

Example source code to do in from C can be downloaded via:

```
apt-get source evtest
```

Python Code can be found at:

- http://svn.navi.cx/misc/trunk/python/evdev/evdev.py